# Cannot select css selector

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am running into an issue where I cannot select the correct CSS selector.  I think the website itself is causing the issue.  Any ideas why it isn't selecting correctly?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import requests, time


driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path="geckodriver")
driver.get("https://www.okcc.online/")
driver.maximize_window()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='rod-menu-button']"))).click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='rodDocTypeTxt']"))).send_keys('MTG')
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//ul[@id='ui-id-1']//li//div"))).click()

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="rod-date-toggle"]').click()

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="rodFromDateTxt"]').send_keys('4/1/2020')
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="rodToDateTxt"]').send_keys('4/20/2020')

search_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="rod-submit-search"]').click()

time.sleep(2)

pdf = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("icon pdf-icon")

print(len(pdf))
```

When I run this, it returns a count of 0, where it should return a count of 50 if I am selecting the CSS correctly on this site.

Ultimately I want to iterate through all of these items, and download the pdf that returns..but I cannot even get the dang thing to be recognized.

Comment: Do you need to preface the selector with a '.' so pdf = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".icon.pdf-icon") as per documentation https://www.seleniumeasy.com/selenium-tutorials/css-selectors-tutorial-for-selenium-with-examples

Answer (score 1):

This will select all elements with compound class icon pdf-icon

```
driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".icon.pdf-icon")
```

This will select all div tags with compound class icon pdf-icon

```
driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div.icon.pdf-icon")
```

More information about css selectors
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

Comment: Please explain what the difference is and why this one works.

Answer (score 0):

Try `div.icon.pdf-icon`.
That is what is suggested here: [Locating Elements](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html)